# How to get an image of an Excel chart out of javascript API Chart.getImage()?

Tags: excel, charts, office-js

I am having an issue with the Chart.getImage() method of Excel javascript API. 
Unlike images generated from VBA, images from the javascript API show a chart not aligned correctly with the image boundaries.

I only tested on Excel client version 16.0.6965.2117 on Windows 10 and have high DPI enabled on windows at 175% scaling. Things get better at 100% but the resulting image is still not pixel perfect.

Here is a code snippet to demonstrate the issue. The red color should not show around the chart if it was aligned on image boundaries because the remaining space is filled with transparency.

```
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        Excel.run(function (ctx) {
            var worksheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
            var chart = worksheet.charts.getItemAt(0).load();
            var chartImgStream = null;

            return ctx.sync()
                .then(function () {
                    chartImgStream = chart.getImage();
                })
                .then(ctx.sync)
                .then(function () {
                    $('#content-main').html('<img src="data:image/png;base64,'+chartImgStream.value+'" style="background-color: red;" />');
                });
        });
    });
}
```

Does anyone have feedback to provide on this method's behaviour on other platforms ?

Comment: We'll test this issue and get back. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Chart.getImage() issue on high scaling device has been solved several months ago. Please upgrade to latest Excel client and try it again. And reach out to me if still any problems.